# .ini cannot locate after pecl install

Tags: php, xdebug, pecl

Trying to install xdebug onto a php vagrant box. I ssh'd into the box and did:

```
pecl install xdebug
```

That seemed to work:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/xdebug-2.2.5
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "zend_extension=xdebug.so" to php.ini
```

But I am not sure where my xdebug.ini is located at? I figured it would create a ini in:

```
 /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini
```

but I don't see one. In fact I can't seem to find xdebug.ini anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your PECL is not configured correctly, so it could not update your php.ini
Now you have two options:

1. add "zend_extension=xdebug.so" to php.ini
2. add  "zend_extension=xdebug.so" to mods-available/xdebug.ini and make sure php.ini includes either that file or the whole directory.